# Nginx php Symlink Getting Document Root

Tags: php, nginx, symlink, silex

I have a Silex PHP site in a folder like the following:

```
/home/user/project/build-19434/
```

Then a symlink for nginx

```
/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site -> /home/user/project/build-19434
```

My web root is

```
/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site/web
```

Now I have a php class that is getting all images from `/home/user/project/build-19434/web/images/gallery/` and building an array. Later I transform those paths like this so I can put them in `<img>` tags:

```
/home/user/project/build-19434/web/images/gallery/img1.jpg
/images/gallery/img1.jpg
```

This doesn't seem to work with the symlink because I am doing the following:

```
public function pathToUrl($path)
{
    $root = $this->request->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT'); // essentially $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
    return str_ireplace($root, '', str_replace("\\", '/', $path));
}
```

My images come from this directory (this is set from a different directory than web)

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../../web/images/gallery';
```

But my $_SERVER vars use the `/usr/share/nginx` paths, and my script to get images is relative to `__DIR__`, which uses the `/home/user` paths. See parts of the server array below (when requesting the gallery/photos page):

```
  array(35) {
    ["USER"]=> string(5) "nginx"
    ["HOME"]=> string(14) "/var/lib/nginx"
    ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(26) "/index.php//gallery/photos"
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(15) "/gallery/photos"
    ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=> string(26) "/index.php//gallery/photos"
    ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(39) "/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site/web"
    ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(49) "/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site/web/index.php"
    ["ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(65) "/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site/web/index.php//gallery/photos"
    ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=> string(39) "/usr/share/nginx/my.site/site/web"
    ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(26) "/index.php//gallery/photos"
  }
```

How can I translate my image paths (which could be symlinked as described), into a web URL? Do I just need to store the `__DIR__` in `index.php` and use that as my root?

I'd prefer a solution that works both on my Windows dev machine (no symlinks, just running directly out of the git repo) and on my production Linux box (uses symlinks to update the project to the latest version).

Comment: I think it's better to rewrite the nginx config to point to the `/home` dir instead of `/usr`, should fix your problems and eliminate the need for the symlink

Comment: But I want to have some fixed nginx configuration (`/usr/share/nginx...`) and multiple app versions (build-294a9, build-40ee, etc.) so I can easily rollback or update the app without changing the nginx config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I can probably rely on `realpath`, because I (should) know the DOCUMENT_ROOT exists. A quick test shows this working on my Linux server.

```
public function pathToUrl($path)
{
    $root = realpath($this->request->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT')); // essentially $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
    return str_ireplace($root, '', str_replace("\\", '/', $path));
}
```

Is there any problem with this solution?

I'm also considering storing the web directory based on `__DIR__` and then normalizing it to remove `../`.